# GL_OES_texture_float not supported on OpenGL ES 3.0 device in a 2.0 context?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-es-3.0

I've got a OpenGL ES 2.0 app that depends on the `GL_OES_texture_float` extension. Pretty much every device in the past 3 years has it, so that's not a problem.

However, using the Galaxy S5 with an Adreno 330 GPU, I've got a problem. The Adreno 330 supports OpenGL ES 3.0, which includes float texture support natively, no extension required. And indeed, grabbing the extension strings from OpenGL on the device does not report `GL_OES_texture_float` as a valid extension.

But when using an OpenGL ES 2.0 context on this device, usages of float textures fail to bind, even though it clearly has the capability since the GPU supports 3.0. It appears it's just not working because I'm in a 2.0 context, and they no longer report it as an extension.

Has anyone else run into a scenario like this?

Comment: I would recommend to create a ES3 context when such exists, since you then would have access to this feature. Consider that there is some fragmentation with OpenGL (ES), and as you found this is probably a bug in the driver.

Comment: Ah I had not originally realized that OGLES 3.0 was backwards compatible with 2.0 shaders, I'll give this a try.

Comment: It is, however you might need to add #version with appropriate version number to the shaders, otherwise it should just work